# Converting JSON objects to unique UTF-8 strings, limited by 750 characters, other ideas are welcomed

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, encoding, utf-8

I have this issue with Google's Firestore and Google's Realtime DB ids/duplicates but I think it is more general problem and it may have multiple solutions without even considering Firebase.

Right now, I create IDs from my JSON object like this:

```
// Preparing data
let data = {
 workouts: [{...}],
 movements: [{...}]
}
// Creating ID from data
const id = btoa(JSON.stringify(data))
// Deleting workouts and movements
delete data.workouts
delete data.movements
// Adding multiple other properties to data objects for example:
data.date = new Date()
... and much more
// Creating new document in DB here or
alerting user it already exists if data.id already exists
```

When I load the data object from Firestore, I decode it like this:

```
const data = JSON.parse(atob(this.workout.id))
```

My goal is to have only unique workouts + movements combinations in my database and generating id based on data from workouts + movements solves it.

The issue is that Realtime DB has limit of 750 Bytes (750 UTF-8 chars per id) and Firestore has limit of 1500 Bytes per id. I have just discovered that by having id that has ~1000 chars. And I believe I would be able to hit even the 1500 chars limit with data from users.

My ideas:

1) Use some different encoding (supporting UTF-8) that will make even long (1000 chars) string to something like 100 chars max. It will still need to be decodable. Is it even possible or Base64 is the shortest it could be?

2) Use autogenerated IDs + save encoded string as data.id parameter to db and when creating new workout always compare this data.id to table of already created workout data.id(s).

- Is it possible to solve without looping through all existing workouts?

3) Any other idea? I am still in the realm of decoding/encoding but I believe it must has a different more simple solution.

Comment: Javascript object properties are unordered. There is no guarantee that two equal JSONs will produce equal string when stringified. Thats why you cant compare two jsons via stringify.

Comment: Why would you think Base64 version of UTF-8 string would be shorter than the original string?

Answer (score 0):

#### Do not `btoa`

First off, Base64 string is probably gonna be longer than the stringified JSON, so if you're struggling with character limit and you can use entire UTF-8, do not `btoa` anything.

#### IDs

You're looking for a hash. You *could* (not recommended) try to roll your own by writing hashing functions for JSON primitives, each must return number:

- `{ ... }` object shall have it's properties sorted by name then hashed
- `string` string shall construct the it's hash from individual characters (`.charCodeAt()`)
- `number` probably can just be kept as-is
- `[ ... ]` Not really sure what would I do with arrays, probably assume different order is different hash and hash them as is

Then you'd deal with the json recursively, constructing the value as:

```
let hash = 0;
hash += hashStringValue("ddd");
hash *= 31;
hash += hashObjectValue({one:1, test:"text"});
return hash
```

The multiplication by a prime before addition is a cheap trick, but this only works fir limited depth of the object.

#### Use library for hash

I googled `javascript hash json` and found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-hash which looks like what you want:

```
// If you're not on babel use:
// require('babel/polyfill')

npm install json-hash

var assert = require('assert')
var hash = require('json-hash')

// hash.digest(any, options?)
assert.equal(hash.digest({foo:1,bar:1}), hash.digest({bar:1,foo:1}))
```

#### Storage

For the storage of JSON data, if you really need it, use compression algorithm such as [`LZString`](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html). You could also filter the JSON and only keep the values you really need.